# Python pandas looking for Non Consecutive Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to find Non- consecutive String duplicates in Pandas Data Frame.
Note: I've used Shift but unable to get desired Output.

Abc
aa
aa
aa
aa
bb
bb
bb
aa
bb
cc
cc
bb
cc
cc

Desired Output:
aa
bb
bb
cc

Comment: what do you mean by "Non- consecutive String duplicates"? Should your expected output be `aa, bb, aa, bb, cc, bb, cc`?

Comment: Non Consecutive String Dup - I mean here I’m considering consecutive duplicate  as non duplicates, To understand where the flips are happening in a column.

Comment: So how is 'cc' in your desired output? @jezrael first answer should be correct

Comment: desired output aa bb bb cc cc because when you see the series aa aa aa aa - consecutive so I’m not considering them as dups and as one grp  but I don’t need that in output next with bb bb bb - same  but again we see aa here which is duplicate and non consecutive. In case of  cc cc  first time we’re are considering it as one and next cc cc as duplicates . Sry, I couldn’t explain better I’m still beginning. My main goal here is to understand flips - the column should have either unique or consecutive elements so if a element falls back after a uniquely consecutive element it’s a flip. Thank you

Comment: Why are you considering `cc` as one : "In case of cc cc first time we’re are considering it as one"-- it should be a consecutive duplicate because it occurs back-to-back. Why would you consider the first instance of `cc` as not a consecutive duplicate but not `aa` and `bb` as well?

Comment: From the order of series of elements- aa aa aa aa - considering as consecutive and unique  bb bb bb - consecutive and unique, aa - considering as non consecutive dup , bb - considering as non consecutive duplicate, cc cc - considering as consecutive and unique , bb - non consecutive and dup, cc cc - consecutive duplicates ( to count their frequency of flips) - to explain in a business view  it’s a transaction id - in that column every row should be either consecutive i mean it should maintain same trans id or new trans id but it shouldn’t call previous old old trans id after different trans id

Comment: OK i think I understand now...so, in your example, your looking to return indices `7,8,11,13`? however, in your explanation not once is `cc` referred to as a non consecutive dup which is what you want returned

Comment: Yes , thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your expected output is not correct...

```
df[df['ABC'].shift(-1) != df['ABC']]

    ABC
3   aa
6   bb
7   aa
8   bb
10  cc
11  bb
13  cc
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the code which I've done for this.

```
a = df[df['ABC'].shift(1) != df['ABC']]
b= df.drop_dupicates('ABC')
c = a[~a.isin(b)]
```

output : aa bb bb cc